# sql finding cid with most expired cards

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `Cards(card_id,status,cid)`

With the columns:

- `cid` - customer id
- `status` - `exp`/`vld`
- `card_id` - card id's

How to find the `cid` with the most expired cards?

Comment: You are lucky that people have answered your question, because it seems you have not made a minimal effort to solve this yourself. What exactly is your problem? Don't you know how to select the rows with status = 'exp'? Don't you know how to count a cid's rows? Anything else? Next time, please show your query and tell us where you got stuck.

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT cid,
       COUNT(*) AS num_exp
FROM   cards
WHERE  status = 'exp'
GROUP BY cid
ORDER BY num_exp DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get count of expired cards for individual customers and then choose customer with MAX count.  The below query should give results.

```
WITH t AS(
SELECT cid, count(1) customer_exp_cards_count
FROM Cards where status = 'exp'
group by cid)
SELECT cid FROM t t1 
WHERE t1.customer_exp_cards_count IN (SELECT MAX(t2.customer_exp_cards_count) 
                                      FROM t t2)
```

Sample data and its result:
cardid status cid

```
3   exp 5
1   exp 1
2   exp 1
3   vld 1
5   vld 1
1   exp 2
2   exp 2
3   exp 2
4   vld 2
5   vld 2
6   exp 3
7   vld 4
4   vld 5
```

Result:
2

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have these two tables (just a sample data)
CUSTOMERS

| CUST_ID | CUST_NAME | CUST_STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | John | ACTIVE |
| 102 | Annie | ACTIVE |
| 103 | Jane | ACTIVE |
| 104 | Bob | INACTIVE |

CARDS

| CARD_ID | CARD_STATUS | CUST_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001001 | VALID | 101 |
| 1001002 | VALID | 101 |
| 1001003 | EXPIRED | 101 |
| 1001004 | EXPIRED | 101 |
| 1001005 | VALID | 101 |
| 1002010 | VALID | 102 |
| 1002020 | EXPIRED | 102 |
| 1002030 | EXPIRED | 102 |
| 1002040 | EXPIRED | 102 |
| 1003100 | VALID | 103 |
| 1003200 | VALID | 103 |

If you want just a CUST_ID with the number of most expired cards you can do it without table CUSTOMERS:

```sql
Select  CUST_ID, EXPIRED_CARDS
From    (Select CUST_ID, Count(CARD_ID) "EXPIRED_CARDS" From cards Where CARD_STATUS = 'EXPIRED' Group By CUST_ID)
Where EXPIRED_CARDS = (Select Max(EXPIRED_CARDS) From (Select Count(CARD_ID) "EXPIRED_CARDS" From cards Where CARD_STATUS = 'EXPIRED' Group By CUST_ID) )
--  
--  R e s u l t
--     CUST_ID EXPIRED_CARDS
--  ---------- -------------
--         102             3
```

Maybe you could consider creating a CTE with the data from both tables which will give you dataset that you could use later for different questions not just for this one. Something like this:

```sql
WITH
  customers_cards AS
    (
        Select
            cst.CUST_ID,
            cst.CUST_NAME,
            cst.CUST_STATUS,
            crd.CARD_ID,
            crd.CARD_STATUS,
            Sum(CASE WHEN crd.CUST_ID Is Null Then 0 Else 1 End) OVER(Partition By crd.CUST_ID) "TOTAL_NUM_OF_CARDS",
            Sum(CASE WHEN crd.CARD_ID Is Null Then Null WHEN crd.CARD_STATUS = 'VALID' And crd.CARD_ID Is Not Null Then 1 Else 0 End) OVER(Partition By crd.CUST_ID) "VALID_CARDS",
            Sum(CASE WHEN crd.CARD_ID Is Null Then Null WHEN crd.CARD_STATUS = 'EXPIRED' And crd.CARD_ID Is Not Null Then 1 Else 0 End) OVER(Partition By crd.CUST_ID) "EXPIRED_CARDS"
        From
            customers cst
        Left Join
            cards crd on(crd.CUST_ID = cst.CUST_ID)
    )
/*  R e s u l t :
   CUST_ID CUST_NAME CUST_STATUS CARD_ID CARD_STATUS TOTAL_NUM_OF_CARDS VALID_CARDS EXPIRED_CARDS
---------- --------- ----------- ------- ----------- ------------------ ----------- -------------
       101 John      ACTIVE      1001001 VALID                        5           3             2 
       101 John      ACTIVE      1001002 VALID                        5           3             2 
       101 John      ACTIVE      1001003 EXPIRED                      5           3             2 
       101 John      ACTIVE      1001004 EXPIRED                      5           3             2 
       101 John      ACTIVE      1001005 VALID                        5           3             2 
       102 Annie     ACTIVE      1002010 VALID                        4           1             3 
       102 Annie     ACTIVE      1002040 EXPIRED                      4           1             3 
       102 Annie     ACTIVE      1002030 EXPIRED                      4           1             3 
       102 Annie     ACTIVE      1002020 EXPIRED                      4           1             3 
       103 Jane      ACTIVE      1003100 VALID                        2           2             0 
       103 Jane      ACTIVE      1003200 VALID                        2           2             0 
       104 Bob       INACTIVE                                         0                          
*/
```

This can be used to answer many more potential questions. Here is the list of customers sorted by number of expired cards (descending):

```sql
Select Distinct
    CUST_ID, CUST_NAME, TOTAL_NUM_OF_CARDS, VALID_CARDS, EXPIRED_CARDS
From
    customers_cards
Order By
    EXPIRED_CARDS Desc Nulls Last, CUST_ID
--  
--  R e s u l t :
--     CUST_ID CUST_NAME TOTAL_NUM_OF_CARDS VALID_CARDS EXPIRED_CARDS
--  ---------- --------- ------------------ ----------- -------------
--         102 Annie                      4           1             3 
--         101 John                       5           3             2 
--         103 Jane                       2           2             0 
--         104 Bob                        0
```

OR to answer your question:

```sql
Select Distinct
    CUST_ID, CUST_NAME, TOTAL_NUM_OF_CARDS, VALID_CARDS, EXPIRED_CARDS
From
    customers_cards
Where
    EXPIRED_CARDS = (Select Max(EXPIRED_CARDS) From customers_cards)
Order By
    CUST_ID
--  
--  R e s u l t :
--     CUST_ID CUST_NAME TOTAL_NUM_OF_CARDS VALID_CARDS EXPIRED_CARDS
--  ---------- --------- ------------------ ----------- -------------
--         102 Annie                      4           1             3
```

Regards...